# React Router Link does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why does the following `<Link>` not work?
When I click on it, I see the URL changes for a slight moment and then it turns back to the current URL, nothing happens on view. I can also see in the Developer Tool the log message: `action @ 14:36:52.677 @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE`

My route definition is:

```
<Route component={MainLayout}>
  <Route path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={TestIndexView} />
    <Route path="test/:code/edit" component={TestFormView} />
</Route>
<Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
```

and the Link is:

```
 <Link to={`test/${item.code}/edit`} className="btn btn-default btn-xs">Edit</Link>
```

I suppose it should render `TestFormView` when I click on the link but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the issue. I configured my project to use `redux-simple-router` instead of `react-router-redux`, that's why it did not work. After changing to `react-router-redux` and import its `routerReducer` module, everything seems to be fine now.